# Плохое качество png при экспорте из sketch в Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, изображения, design, png

Когда я экспортирую изображения из sketch в Xcode все выглядит отлично:
[image: Качество при экспорте]

Но как только я использую хоть одну из этих картинок для кнопки получается это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Размеры первоначальных изображений 35*35p
Как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: На чем тестируете?

Comment: @ВикторМишустин использую встроенный эмулятор iphone 8

Comment: iphone 8 использует преобразование пикселей x2, добавьте в asset x2

Comment: @ВикторМишустин пробывал - ничего не выходит